# I want to combine two dataframe with the same names columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to combine these Dataframe:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Nombre': [Elisa Perez],
    'Fecha': [2/04/2019],
    'Sexo': [np.nan],
    'Nacionalidad': [np.nan],
    'Ciudad': [Roma]})

df_b = pd.DataFrame(data={
    'Nombre': [Elisa Perez],
    'Fecha': [2/04/2019],
    'Sexo': [mujer],
    'Nacionalidad': [Italiana],
    'Ciudad': [Roma]})
```

and I want automatically this result without have to write each columns names in the code:

```
    Nombre       Fecha       Sexo       Nacionalidad       Ciudad
0 Elisa Perez  2/04/2019     mujer       Italiana           Roma
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for columns for matching:

```
df = (df_b.set_index(['Nombre','Fecha'])
          .combine_first(df_a.set_index(['Nombre','Fecha']))
          .reset_index())
```